Can I configure a custom (separate) Downloads folder for web apps that I access via VSCode?
I am testing a web application, which I access with use of VSCode debug tool for Chrome. This allows me to separate the default web browser and the testing web browser.
I was wondering if there's a way to configure the Downloads folder for the browser that I use for testing without changing the defaul Downloads folder that I have configured in the default Chrome browser.
My goal is to not mix testing data with my personal browsing data
Here's a JSON that I use for opening the web app:
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch App in Chrome",
            "url": "https://myApplicationURL/",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "runtimeArgs": ["--incognito"]
        }
    ]
} 

Is there any argument that could be used in JSON that will override Chrome's default setting?
Best case scenario is, that I would have a separate Downloads folder for each of my testing folders (there will be quite a few of those).
I found out that I can change these settings manually in Chrome via Settings -> Downloads, but I'm looking for a different way - ideally with a peace of code.

I tried to look up some advice online, but this seems like a very niche question.
Maybe I'm not asking this correctly, but I will try to explain if anyone needs further information.
Thanks!
